# List View con base de datos

Tags: android-sqlite

Quisiera saber que me falta para que muestre al menos un valor.

Este es el error:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
>   android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a
>   null object reference
>           at monchis.com.py.pruebabd.MainActivity.consultarResultado(MainActivity.java:124)
>           at monchis.com.py.pruebabd.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:41)

Este es el código:

```
public void consultarResultado(){

        AdminSQLiteOpenHelper admin= new AdminSQLiteOpenHelper(this,"administracion",null,1);

        SQLiteDatabase bd= admin.getWritableDatabase();


        Cursor fila= bd.rawQuery("select * from usuario ", null);

       fila.moveToFirst();

        while(fila.isAfterLast()){
            list.add(fila.getString(0));
            fila.moveToNext();

        }

        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,list);
        dynamicListView.setAdapter(adapter);




    }
```

Comment: Asegúrate que dynamicListView está declarado antes de  llamar al método consulatarResultado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primero verifica que tu ListView es creado antes de llamar al método **consultarResultado();**

Podrías hacer el enlace a tú listview en el onCreate u onResume de la actividad para que siempre tengas una referencia al elemento.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.miActividadLayout);

    //Obtener la referencia del ListView
    miListView =  findViewById(R.id.mi_list_view);

   //Luego consultar y estás seguro que tu elemento no sea nulo
    consultarResultado();
}
```

Otro caso sería asegurarte que el listView no sea nulo antes de hacer cualquier cosa.

```
public void consultarResultado(){
    if(miListView == null){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "El listView es nulo", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }

    // Codigo a ejecutar sino es nulo
}
```

También puedes acceder al listView en caso de que sea nulo para obtener su referencia y luego continuar con lo que sigue. Ejemplo:

```
public void consultarResultado(){
    if(miListView == null){
        //Te aseguras de obtener el listview
        miListView =  findViewById(R.id.mi_list_view);
    }

    // Codigo a ejecutar 
}
```

Comment: Ya probé iniciando antes de mi método pero igual no funciona, me sale el mismo error.

Comment: ¿Estás seguro? ¿Seguro que los nombres son correctos y el listview se encuentra en el layout en el cuál está tu actividad.?¿Podrías poner el layout y donde haces la llamada al método de consulta? Me parece un caso muy extraño. @VictorArrúa

Answer (score 0):

Si entiendo bien tu código *(y el mensaje del error)*, dice que en esta línea:

```
dynamicListView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

El parámetro `adapter` es NULL. Debes verificar que el valor que le pasas a `dynamicListView.setAdapter` no no sea `NULL`.

Actualización: de acuerdo al [comentario del usuario Dionicio](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/228966/list-view-con-base-de-datos/228972?noredirect=1#comment425260_228972):

> El listView es nulo dado que el error dice que falla al intentar
>   invocar al método `setAdapter()` en una referencia nula.

Para mas información de cómo solucionar este error, lee: **[¿Cuál es la solución a todos los errores NullPointerException presentes, pasados y futuros?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/42978/78)**

Comment: El listView es nulo dado que el error dice  que falla al intentar invocar al método setAdapter() en una referencia nula.

Comment: @Dionicio gracias por tu aporte. He editado mi respuesta, pero, si consideras que tu comentario es correcto, deberías publicarlo como respuesta. Saludos.